# Linux - dd command is failing with error [no space left on device]

Tags: cygwin, dd

I am currently trying to create an image of a USB key to create a backup. The USB key is 128G and the target External Hard drive has 300G available approximately.

I am using Cygwin and here is What I do so you understand :

I place myself on the External hard drive by typing : cd E: I end up under /cygdrive/e which is my HDD. The usb key is under/cygdrive/d

Here is what cat /proc/partitions gives :

```
$ cat /proc/partitions major minor #blocks name win-mounts

8     0 250059096 sda
8     1    266240 sda1
8     2     16384 sda2
8     3 248955904 sda3   C:\
8     4    819200 sda4
8    16 125091840 sdb
8    17 125091584 sdb1   D:\
8    32 312571224 sdc
8    33 312568641 sdc1   E:\
```

So here is the DD command I launch:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 | pv -s 128G | dd of=backup.usb.img bs=1M
```

It starts and progress well each time until it fails with the error :

```
dd: error writing ‘backup.usb.img’: No space left on device
```

I tried several times, and each time it fails after reading around 4,2G. My HDD has like 300G available so I don't understand...

Why is the dd command failing with a no space left whereas the target has plenty of space available ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The HDD is formatted as FAT32 so it only supports files up to 4GiB = 4.29GB. Either write it to a different FS or split it up int 4G chunks.

Comment: Wow thank you very much ! I was desperate about this. So I understand different FS, I could reformat in NTFS ? And How can I split it in 4G chunks ? Using bs=4G ?

Comment: You can reformat to NTFS. Of course it will wipe all your current data. If the filesystem is already NTFS, try removing the `pv` in the middle and go one step only : dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=backup.usb.img bs=1M

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, reply from "that other guy" solved my issue.

I formatted my DD into exFat to it can be used on MacOS as well, and the DD command went fine.

Also thanks "Matzeri", because I also removed the pv in the middle.
We can use : status=progress
It just needs sys-apps/coreutils >= 8.24

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what "@that other guy" mentioned with respect to splitting the file into 4G chunks so it would fit on a FAT32 disk, I had to do something like that earlier this year.

I needed to view the contents of a Mac OSX 2280 SSD, but couldn't on the non-Mac workstation I was on. The only Mac I had at my disposal was behind lock and key, i.e. no physical USB to plug in the adapter. My solution was to `dd` the disk image piped into `ssh`, sending it to the Mac, and mount it like an image file.

This should've worked:

```
dd if=${InputDev} bs=1M status=progress | ssh user@${DESTHOST} "dd bs=1M of=${OUTPUTFILENAME}"
```

The problem I ran into is that something between the two computers caused some network problems, so I would have to restart the entire clone operation. I ended up sending 10 or 100 MB at a time, then whichever chunk failed, I resent manually. I used something like this.

```
# For demonstration purposes, this example splits ${InputDev}, a 1 GiB file,
#   into 10 100 MiB pieces, plus an 11th piece with the remaining data.
# Note that the last couple chunks result in empty files at $DESTHOST 
#   because it tries to skip past EOF on the input side.
# When chunking with ssh, it's best to use an SSH key for the transfer.

for chunk in $(seq -w 0 12)
# "-w" in seq above ensures leading zeroes to keep files in order
do
    echo "Sending chunk #${chunk} of ${InputDev}"
    dd \
        if=${InputDev} \
        bs=100M \
        skip=${chunk} \
        count=1 \
        status=progress | \
            ssh root@${DESTHOST} "dd bs=100M of=/tmp/DevSdx_chunk#_${chunk}.dd"
        echo ""
done
```

For your scenario, where you can plug in a USB drive on the same machine, you wouldn't need the pipe into `ssh` portion. You would add `of=/media/MyUSB/DevSdx_chunk#_${chunk}.dd` to the `dd` command.

After the operations are finished, you can compare the source and destination checksums to verify integrity.

```
# Source side
sha256sum ${InputDev}
5f9c534c0753deb7188ae645928165d16f5e7378c1257532faa1bcb17a69740d  ${InputDev}

# Destination side
# if your output files are out of lexicographical order, the checksum won't match
cat /media/MyUSB/DevSdx_chunk*.dd | sha256sum # if local
cat /tmp/DevSdx_chunk*.dd | sha256sum # using the ssh example
```

If the checksums match on both ends, you can reassemble the whole image on the destination side with

```
# Destination side
cat /media/MyUSB/DevSdx_chunk*.dd > /media/FileSystemThatAllowsLargerFiles/DevSdx.dd
```